# How to include the boundary values while using spring data jpa

Tags: spring-boot

I am writing an application which contains an entity with property named addedDate of type Date.
I have written an interface which extends MongoRepository and defined a method named 
`findByAddedDateBetween(Date startDate,Date endDate);`
But when I query with 2 dates the output only contain list entities between the dates,Not including the entities whose addedDates is the queried dates. I want to include the boundary values also.

Answer (score 0):

[According to Spring JPA documentation for MongoDB](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries), the between keyword is not inclusive in Mongo DB if you use 2 parameters.

As an alternative, you can use the spring Range class. You must use this method in order to include boundaries.

```
findByAddedDateBetween(Range<Date> range)
```

Where Range is declared like this :

```
Range<Date> range = Range.of(Range.Bound.inclusive(dateStart), Range.Bound.inclusive(dateEnd));
```

Comment: I am using like :```@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
 private Date addedDate``` and in DB when I save a date it is stored as ```"addedDate" : ISODate("2019-10-10T00:00:00Z")```

Comment: in mongodb I think the interpretation for between keyword is ```$gt addedDate and $lt addedDate```, In sql I think between is ```$gte addedDate and $lte addedDate```

Comment: I don't know well MongoDB, but in Potsgres for intance, the between keyword is interpreted as  `where addedDate between startDate and endDate`. As an alternative, you can also use JPA keywords GreaterThanEqual and LessThanEqual which are equivalent to gte and lte.

Comment: When I execute the above mentioned method am getting: ```org.springframework.data.mongodb.InvalidMongoDbApiUsageException: Due to limitations of the com.mongodb.BasicDocument, you can't add a second 'addedDate' expression specified as 'addedDate : Document{{$lte=Wed Nov 20 05:30:00 IST 2019}}'. Criteria already contains 'addedDate : Document{{$gte=Wed Sep 11 05:30:00 IST 2019}}'.```

Comment: I updated my answer, I think you need to use the Spring Range class in order to use the between keyword in inclusive mode.